# How do I upload an image to Google Drive with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api

I'm using the resumable upload from Google Drive API v3

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#resumable

The POST appears successful. I've received a 200 with a Location header containing my session URI.

I'm able to PUT data to that URI, and see it uploaded. However the resulting file is about a third larger than my local JPEG, is untitled, and cannot be opened once downloaded.

This is the code which loads the file

```
fr = new FileReader(); // FileReader instance
    fr.onloadend = function () {
        fileData = fr.result;
        console.log("fileData.length = " + fileData.length);

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = fileData;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    };
    //fr.readAsText( file );
    fr.readAsDataURL( file );
    //fr.readAsBinaryString(file);
    //fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

As you can see, I add the image to page. It is shown successfully. (you can also see that I've trial and errored a lot with FileReader (all error!))

This is the code for the PUT

```
$.ajax
({
    url: resumableSessionURI,
    type: "PUT",
    headers:
    {
        "X-Upload-Content-Length": fileSize,
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    data: fileData
});
```

I get a 200 back, and a new untitled file in Google Drive.

The local file is 4,751,758 bytes. The length of filedata is 6,335,703 bytes (but still renders in the page correctly). The file downloaded from Google Drive is also 6,335,703 bytes. Is the data the wrong format?

Comment: just from that 30% number, seems your data is still encoded. atob/btoa

Comment: btoa makes it larger, atob won't run ("The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded"). Doesn't look like it's encoded.

Comment: `readAsDataURL` returns a base64 encoded string.  Your content type on the upload is `image/jpeg`.  Not sure if this is an issue?

Comment: Could be, but not sure what to change it to. I tried adding `"Content-transfer-encoding": "base64"`. I tried removing it (you never know!) but it just defaulted to being nonsense document instead of a nonsense image.